# Control - M | Mass update 'Active Environment Retention' from Forever to 1 day

Tags: automation, devops, control-m, workload

Problem is with Control-M Version 9,

Multiple occasions I've tried to mass update the retention of jobs with control-m's mass update tool, i can use this for almost anything else however with this particular feature i can't get it working.

Does anyone know of any guides? I've looked round and have not been able to find people using it to amend environment retention only other things, which I've also been able to do in the past.

I've had a good play, and am now at my witts end, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all,

Jack

Comment: I’ve certainly used the mass update tool to update the max wait variable in the past so it should work. Another option would be to download all your jobs in XML and do a find/replace in a text editor then import that XML file.

Comment: @JooBear I'll give that a go and get back to you - seems like the fastest/easiest solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing the mass update in the Active Environment (**AJF**) then you could try using the **ctmpsm** command.

Answer (score 0):

Mass update active environment retention:

[image: Mass update active environment retention]